# jQuery DataTables - Send URL parameter with Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) with Ajax-sourced data and pagination. Each time when I click pagination link the same Ajax URL is called.

How can I send different offset to load records accordingly?

Comment: use bootsrap data table . it will add pagination

Comment: study this link http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.VcCLdnWlyko

Comment: @majoj Bhiman, adding pagination is not problem. The problem for me is to use pagination with ajax

Comment: show your code . and where is the problem.

Comment: I have resolved the above problem. Now I am facing on problem that pagination numbers below the table are not shown correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option.

For example, to send current page number as URL parameter use the code below:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({       
   "ajax": {
     "url": "/getNextPageData",
     "data": function(){
        var api = $('#example').DataTable();

        // Get paging information
        var info = api.page.info();

        // Update URL
        // Send page number as a parameter
        api.ajax.url(
           "/getNextPageData/" + (info.page + 1)
        );
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for pagination:

```
function pagination(val)
{
  var pageurl='yourPage.php';
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:pageurl+'?page='+val,
       success: function(data){
       $('.element').html(data);
       }});
}
```

Define this function in your pagination in html like that 
`<a onclick='pagination("<?= $i ?>")' href='yourPage.php?page=".$i."'><?=$i?> </a>`